# Record access during Manual sharing

Tags: apex, permissions, sharing, customization

This might sound very basic but I was not able to find the right documentation for this.

Suppose I have a record whose Owner is X. Once X fills out the record and saves it, the record type changes and a few more fields are added to the record. Now I want to change the ownership to Y in such a way that Y should be able to edit the record which X should be able to only view it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple actually. Hand't searched for it in the right manner.

I set the OWD for that object as Public Read-Only and then change the OwnerId to Y. Now, Y will be able to edit and X can only view it.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, this is more or less the idea behind changing ownership. Say you have OWD public r/w on the object, then changing the ownership would automatically lead to the behaviour you desire.

If your question is how to change ownership automatically based on criteria in the record, you can use a workflow rule and field update for that.

Suggested documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&language=en

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_workflow_intro.htm